# Using perspective and transform: translateZ to create a Parallax effect - how do I base the scroll on the body and not on the container?

Tags: css, transform, parallax, perspective

[My Demo](http://codepen.io/JoshuaSoileau/pen/bdBrzQ)

I've created the parallax effect lower down on the page (which is the location that I want it to appear).

But the parallax effect is based on the scroll from the overflow of **ONLY** that section of the page, not the scroll of the entire page.

How do I get the parallax effect to happen as the entire page scrolls, not just once I scroll through the parallax containing element? I don't want scrollbars to appear on the parallax section in FF & IE (not that this would work in IE regardless).

---

Here's my pertinent CSS:

```
.parallax {
  background: lightgrey;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1px;
  perspective-origin-x: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 300px;
}
.parallax .layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 60px;
}
.parallax .layer:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: #F06D61;
  transform: translateZ(-4px) scale(5);
  top: -340px;
}
.parallax .layer:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: #DA825F;
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
  top: 140px;
}
.parallax .layer:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: #C4975C;
  transform: translateZ(0) scale(1);
  top: 230px;
}
```

Comment: Try looking at this: http://www.jarallax.com/